# R: logit{gregmisc}

Tags: r

I want to do a logistic transformation on a variable, specifying upper and lower boundaries. I tried to replicated the "logit" function in the [gregmisc package](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/gregmisc/html/logit.html) :

```
  library(gregmisc)
  x <- seq(0,10, by=0.25)
  xt <- logit(x, min=0, max=10)
```

but I get an error message:

```
Error in logit(x, min = 0, max = 10) : 
  unused argument(s) (min = 0, max = 10)
```

What gives? (P.S. gtools doesn't work either).

Here's the sessionInfo():

```
> library(gregmisc)    
+ x <- seq(0,10, by=0.25)
+ xt <- logit(x, min=0, max=10)
Error in logit(x, min = 0, max = 10) : 
  unused argument(s) (min = 0, max = 10)
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] car_2.0-10      survival_2.36-9 nnet_7.3-1      MASS_7.3-13    
 [5] gregmisc_2.1.1  gplots_2.8.0    caTools_1.12    bitops_1.0-4.1 
 [9] gtools_2.6.2    gmodels_2.15.1  gdata_2.8.2     foreign_0.8-44 
[13] rkward_0.5.6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.13.0
```

Comment: This works on my machine.  Can you post more information about your R and gregmisc versions?  One clue is that library(gregmisc) returns a warning:
Warning message:

 <<The `gregmisc' *package* has converted into a *bundle*
 containing four sub-packages: gdata, gtools, gmodels, and 
        gplots. Please load these packages directly.>> 

Perhaps you're stuck with an older or incompatible version of gregmisc?

Comment: works for me, as long as **gregmisc** has been installed with it's dependencies. What do you mean by you "tried to replicate" it? Does it work if you do `library(gtools)` and then run the `logit()` call. If the `library()` call throws an error, it might mean you don't have the unbundled packages installed that used to be in the **gregmisc** bundle. Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()` **after** you have run the code snippet you show?

Comment: This also works for me. Check to see if `logit()` is defined in one of the other packages loaded: do this by `conflicts()`. If there is a conflict, then you can specify the `gregmisc` version by calling `gregmisc::logit()`

Comment: Something looks wrong there. Why is the prompt a `+` for your two lines of R code setting up `x` and calling `logit()`? Is this an *exact* copy-paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is that you have the `car` package loaded as well, which also contains a `logit` function.

```
find("logit")
```

would have shown you

```
[1] "package:car"    "package:gtools"
```

They have different sets of arguments:

```
> names(formals(car::logit))
[1] "p"        "percents" "a
> names(formals(gtools::logit))
[1] "x"   "min" "max"
```

Either specifying `gtools::logit` explicitly or doing `detach("package:car")` should make things work.